# XPages: centering icon and text in a lotusMessage panel

Tags: xpages

I have this code:

```
<xp:panel styleClass="lotusMessage" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:'<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle fa-2x pull-left fa-fw"></i>'}]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.sortedSearchResults.errorMsg !=""}]]></xp:this.rendered>

                <xp:text escape="true" styleClass="textmiddle" style="font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,0)">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:if(!!sessionScope.sortedSearchResults) {
    var msg = sessionScope.sortedSearchResults.errorMsg; 
    if( msg !="") {
        msg;
    }
}}]]></xp:this.value>

            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
```

The font-awesome icon and text are not vertically aligned, but I would like them to be (as for all lotusMessage panels).

Is there a quick way to center vertically?

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a custom.css file, and have it load after the oneUI stylesheets (if you don't already).
2. Use Google Chrome inspect element  (or Firebug) to isolate the class of the object that you want to style (probably lotusMessage like you mention, but definitely check)
3. Play with the padding like this:

   padding-top:0.250em;
        padding-bottom:0.250em; (These are just possible suggestions)
4. Override the CSS in your custom.css file
5. Go back into Chrome and make sure your styles are loading
6. Use `!important` only if necessary. Sometimes your styles get overridden by the more specific oneUI styles.

Note: With chrome you can actually add styles and see how they look, when you like the result you can then copy into your custom stylesheet.

Here is a post I wrote on overwriting styles that might help: 
http://notesspeak.blogspot.com/2014/10/quick-tip-forcing-css-override.html